# strtotime logical error in comparing dates

Tags: php

I'm having a problem regarding comparing two dates. I know this sound kinda silly but I want you all to try this example.

```
$a = date('d-m-Y', strtotime('2014-07-03'));
$b = date('d-m-Y', strtotime('2014-03-17'));
$c = date('d-m-Y', strtotime('2015-03-16'));

if(($a > $b)  && ($a < $c) ) {
    echo "1";
}
else {
    echo "2";
}
```

How come the result is 2?

Comment: I am seeing the future, you will be visited by some form of super greater power.

Comment: you're comparing strings, not dates. PHP has **NO** idea that `01-02-03` is a date. it's just a series of characters.

Answer (score 14):

Your "logic" is wrong.

[image: xkcd]
> [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/1179/)

```
$a = '2014-07-03';
$b = '2014-03-17';
$c = '2015-03-16';

if(($a > $b) && ($a < $c)) {
    echo "1"; // it works!
}
```

Big-endian formats are awesome.

Answer (score 4):

Because your date format is *not* good for comparing. Always use YYYY-MM-DD format when comparing dates (or use DateTime() objects). This is because 04-01-2014 is less than 05-01-2014 when compared as strings.

```
$a = '2014-07-03';
$b = '2014-03-17';  
$c = '2015-03-16';  

if(($a > $b)  && ($a < $c) ) {
    echo "1";
}
else {
    echo "2";
}
```

Or when using DateTime() objects:

```
$a = new DateTime('2014-07-03');
$b = new DateTime('2014-03-17');
$c = new DateTime('2015-03-16');

if(($a > $b)  && ($a < $c) ) {
    echo "1";
}
else {
    echo "2";
}
```

Comment: Ah, there you are. [I thought](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24556316/strtotime-logical-error-in-comparing-dates#comment38032155_24556316) you'd never get here lol

Comment: Sorry I'm late. Was distracted by an AngularJS issue I need to sort out.

Comment: Don't sweat it and no need to be sorry ;-) Sorry is when you've missed out on a great cup of coffee which has gone cold, but... then again, some like it cold. Gaspacho anyone?

Comment: AngularJS, *right*. You were out in some phone booth somewhere, making out with Lois Lane.

Comment: You're able to go back in time, so problem solved. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

After your date/strtotime function, you have :

```
$a = '03-07-2014'
$b = '17-03-2014'
$c = '16-03-2015'
```

So when you compare, $a is less than $b because it compares the day first.